# CDI injection when instantiating bean manually

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld, inject

I know this kind of question is coming back regurarly but I wonder if there is a way to instantiate manually a bean (with new Xxxx()) and have my injection done.
Maybe using BeanManager but I don't find how to.

If it is not possible, I wonder why this has not be done. Conceptually I don't find a good reason for making this not possible.

Thanks for your explanation.

P.S : i'm working with JBoss 7.1.1 and Weld CDI container.

JM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a fundamental concept behind CDI is the notion of scopes and their associated context. That's the *Contexts* in Contexts and Dependency Injection. Basically, a bean with a scope has a well defined life cycle, but when you instantiate a bean yourself there is no longer telling what its life cycle is. Read section [2.4 Scopes](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#d0e1066) of the CDI spec.

To give you slightly more insight - CDI does not only `@Inject` your dependencies, but also manages their life cycle. That extends beyond simple instanciation and dependency injection, into termination (calling `@PreDestroy`) not only for the bean instance itself, but also for all the dependent instances. When you instanciate a bean yourself there is no telling when to do that last part.